# (React native )After running signed apk undefiend code:-1 error displaying https domain

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am using the **https** domain.

I have created a react native app after i launched my signed apk after installing it showing . 
Error loading page
 Domine undefined
 Error code :-1
Description:net::ERR_ClEARTEXT_Not_Permited[image]

````
  package="com.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>```
````

Comment: can you share androidManifest file and some code here

Comment: muhammad the problem is with the http url in my code in web view android app support only https

Comment: try this in manifest  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:networkSecurityConfig` user permission and `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`  in manifest

```
   package="com.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/react_native_config" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

create file at `res/xml/react_native_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```